# Airtable - Formatting 'url' fields using vue js

Tags: api, vue.js, hyperlink, formatting, airtable

back again with another question, regarding formatting data pulled from Airtable:

Just using the steps provided [here](https://medium.com/row-and-table/an-basic-intro-to-the-airtable-api-9ef978bb0729) to embed some Airtable data into a basic html format that I can style.

The issue: How can I format the data coming through into a href link?

I'm assuming it's not how I'm currently doing it

The JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hawkette/bw4rp0xa/3/)

```html
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in items">
            <h3>{{ item['fields']['Name'] }}</h3>
            <a :href="item['fields']['Link']['url']" v-if="item['fields']['Link']">
                <p>Title: {{ item['fields']['Title'] }}</p>
            </a>
            <p>
                <strong>Link: </strong>
                {{ item['fields']['Link'] }}
            </p>                
        </li>
    </ul>            
</div><!--app-->
```

The JS:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.loadItems();
  },
  methods: {
    loadItems: function() {
      // Init variables
      var self = this;
      var app_id = "---";
      var app_key = "---";
      this.items = [];
      axios
        .get(
          "https://api.airtable.com/v0/" +
            app_id +
            "/Characters?view=Grid%20view",
          {
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + app_key }
          }
        )
        .then(function(response) {
          self.items = response.data.records;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a method `formatUrl`

```js
methods: {
    formatUrl(url) {
        return url.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

And then just pass your value

```html
<a v-if="item['fields']['Link']" :href="formatUrl(item['fields']['Link']['url'])">
    <p>Title: {{ item['fields']['Title'] }}</p>
</a>
```

Also, you could use `filters`

```js
filters: {
  formatUrl(value) {
    return url.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

And during rendering

```html
<a v-if="item['fields']['Link']" :href="item['fields']['Link']['url'] | formatUrl">
    <p>Title: {{ item['fields']['Title'] }}</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Not sure if that's exactly what I need - I'm attempting to have the data, which is a URL, be inserted into the <a href="INSERT URL HERE">other data</a>. Which doesn't seem to be happening. Please see JSFiddle

Tested with the filters format... no data shows up at all now

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I actually think I got it! 
Just needed to change the ahref link to this:

`<a :href="item['fields']['Link']"> stuff here </a>`